# how to obtain information about installed application on managed devices within an enterprise using android management api?

Tags: android-management-api

I am currently working on an MDM (Mobile Device Management) Application that utilizes the Android Management API. I have successfully enrolled my devices and obtained some application details such as SDK version and app versions by using on node js.

```
   // Fetch the application details
    const appDetails = await androidmanagement.enterprises.applications.get({
      name: `enterprises/${enterpriseName}/applications/${packageName}`,
      auth: client,
    });

 console.log(appDetails.data)
```

i refer this [link](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.applications#AppTrackInfo)

However, I am facing challenges in retrieving the following details:

```
1.App Installed on devices
2.Build Number
3.Release Tag
4.install app File Size
```

I have thoroughly reviewed the documentation and explored various approaches, but I haven't been able to find a solution for these specific details. Therefore, I am reaching out to seek your expertise and assistance in resolving this matter.

If you could kindly guide me on how to obtain the above-mentioned application details through the Android Management API or provide any relevant code examples, it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve the specific application details mentioned, you can use the Android Management API as follows:

**App Installed on Devices:**

To get information about the applications installed on a specific device, you can use the [applicationReports](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices#applicationreport:%7E:text=applicationReports%5B%5D) field from the [enterprises.devices](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.devices) API.

**Build Number and Release Tag:**

Assuming Build Number refers to the App's Version Code, and Release Tag can be either the App’s Track Alias, Track ID, or Version String, we can use the [enterprises.applications](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.applications) API to obtain all of the following information under [AppTrackInfo](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.applications#apptrackinfo) and [AppVersion](https://developers.google.com/android/management/reference/rest/v1/enterprises.applications#appversion) fields.

**Install App File Size:**

Unfortunately, there is no direct API within the Android Management API to retrieve the install app file size.

Comment: In the applicationReport lists, do not have an enrolled device for my own privately installed applications lists, although the device has it installed.

Comment: Thanks,@Clark Samson I got the applications installed on a specific device at enterprise devices within nonComplianceDetails